# Block a user using Open Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, block

Is it possible to block a user on Facebook using the open graph API?

I am NOT looking to block a user from an App, but would like to allow users to block a facebook friend if they wish in my app. This would be the same as visiting Facebook.com and blocking a user which hides them from all of your feeds etc.

So far I have done a lot of digging and cannot find an answer. Still pouring over API but figured I would see if anyone has nay experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to modify a user's friend list or blocked list via the API

Comment: Are you familiar with the same concept in Google Plus? Does their API allow blocking a user as well?

Comment: No idea, i'm not familiar with the G+ API, but at first glance it seems to be read-only: https://developers.google.com/+/api/